# Google Apps Script Save copy to read only

Tags: google-apps-script

How do you save a copy of the current Sheets file to a read-only copy? We have scripts that set values that once confirmed save to a new Sheets file. This new file needs to be set as ReadOnly as a part of the script.

Answer (score 2):

In your situation, how about using content protection?

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
const fileId = "###"; // Please set the file ID. In your situation, please set the Spreadsheet ID.
Drive.Files.patch({contentRestrictions: [{readOnly: true}]}, fileId);
```

- When this script is run, the Spreadsheet can be only viewed and the Spreadsheet cannot be written.
- If you want to unprotect it, please modify `{readOnly: true}` to `{readOnly: false}` in the above script.

#### References:

- [Protect file content from modification](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/file-locking)
- [Files: patch](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/patch)

Comment: Thanks.  That might work but wanted to save a copy and have it protected.  Came up with an alt solution.  Just saved it to a PDF! :)

Answer (score 1):

- A Google Sheets file will always be editable by the file onwer
- It will not accesiable by other users it all unless it is explicitly shared with them
  -The sharing can take place either through the UI or by script
- To do it by script, you can use the method [Spreadsheet.addViewer()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#addViewer(String)) or [File.addViewer()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file?hl=en#addvieweremailaddress)
- If a user who has is already an editor needs to be "downgraded" to a viewer, you can do remove him from the editors with [removeEditor()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet?hl=en#removeeditoremailaddress) before adding him as a viewer
- You can also remove all editors (apart from the spreadsheet owner), sample:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
ss.getEditors().forEach(function(editor){
  ss.removeEditor(editor):
})
```

Comment: I thought that `+` of `var ss + SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();` might be a mistype.

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike! I have the `+`  and the   `=` on the same key :-)

Comment: Wow! It's your custom keyboard? That's nice!

Comment: Unfortunately no @Tanaike, it is a common keyboard layout for US/UK keyboards. But it's an interesting idea about getting one's own custom keyboard :-)

Comment: Thank you for replying. That is new information for me. In the Japanese keyboard I'm using,`-` and `=` are the same. And, `;` and `+` are the same. I sometimes mistype them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DriveApp [Permission](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/permission) enum, [`.setSharing`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#setSharing(Access,Permission)), and related methods to do this.

Assuming you have a reference to the [File](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file) object represented by the new Sheets file, this function will change all sharing so that the file is "View only" for anyone who previously had edit permission.

```
/**
 * Change sharing permissions on a file or folder.
 * @param {File or Folder object} asset 
 */
function makeViewOnly(asset)
{
  // General sharing permissions: change VIEW to NONE if you only want specific people to view the file
  asset.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
  asset.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
  // These only apply if the file is on a Workspace domain.
  asset.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.DOMAIN, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
  asset.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.DOMAIN_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);

  // Change all edit permissions to view permissions
  users = asset.getEditors();
  user.forEach(function (user) { 
    asset.removeEditor(user) 
    asset.addViewer(user)
  });
}
```

If you have a reference to the [Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet) object for the newly created Sheets file instead of the File object, you can get the File object via

```
var asset = DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheet.getId())
```